# React Hook not setting with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useEffect` to fetch some data from Trello and set some states. First I grab the card I'm looking for and call `setCard` and `setCardLocation`. Everything is working fine. Then I get into my `else` case and no matter what I do `setPublishDate` will never be set, the loop continues to run. Why do all of these other hooks work but my last one doesn't? Thanks.

```
export default function Home(props) {
  const [performedFetch, setPerformedFetch] = useState(false);
  const [slug, setSlug] = useState(null);
  const [cardLocation, setCardLocation] = useState(1);
  const [card, setCard] = useState(null);
  const [publishDate, setPublishDate] = useState(null);

  const key = ''; // imagine these are here
  const token = '';

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlug(
      new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('slug')
    );

    if (!performedFetch && !!slug) {
      fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${listId}/cards?key=${key}&token=${token}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setPerformedFetch(true);

            data.forEach((c, index) => {
              if (c.desc.includes(slug)) {                    
                setCard(c)
                setCardLocation(index + 1)
              } else if (!publishDate && index > cardLocation) { 
                console.log(publishDate); // why is this always null?? also runs multiple times

                const name = c.name;
                const frontHalf = name.split("/")[0].split(" ");
                const month = frontHalf[frontHalf.length - 1];
                const day = name.split("/")[1].split(")")[0];
                setPublishDate(`${month}/${day}`);
              }
            });
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think this is related to this: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Two `useEffect()` as @TaghiKhavari says, or just use slug locally within the useEffect - `const slug = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('slug')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by [@TaghiKhavari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61843348/2873538), you should have two `useEffects` ([Multiple effects to separate concerns](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns)).

Also, it is important to [optimize the performance by skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) by **providing a dependency array** as *second argument* to the `useEffect`. So the effect will only re-run if any of its dependencies would change.

First effect for `slug`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSlug(
    new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('slug')
  );
}, []) // Note: Remove "[]" if you want to set slug at each update / render Or keep it if you want to set it only once (at mount)
```

Second effect to fetch and set card and other details:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!performedFetch && slug) {
    fetch(
      `https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${listId}/cards?key=${key}&token=${token}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPerformedFetch(true)

      // Note: if there can be only ONE matching card
      const index = data.findIndex((card) => card.desc.includes(slug))
      if (index > -1) {
        const card = data[index]
        setCard(card)
        setCardLocation(index + 1)
        const name = card.name
        const frontHalf = name.split('/')[0].split(' ')
        const month = frontHalf[frontHalf.length - 1]
        const day = name.split('/')[1].split(')')[0]
        setPublishDate(`${month}/${day}`)
      }

      // Setting State in a LOOP? is a problem
      /*
      data.forEach((card, index) => {
        if (card.desc.includes(slug)) {
          setCard(card)
          setCardLocation(index + 1)
        } else if (!publishDate && index > cardLocation) {
          const name = card.name
          const frontHalf = name.split('/')[0].split(' ')
          const month = frontHalf[frontHalf.length - 1]
          const day = name.split('/')[1].split(')')[0]
          setPublishDate(`${month}/${day}`)
        }
      })*/

    })
  }
}, [slug, performedFetch])
```

[Set states may be async to improve performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

So, you should not set states in a loop as you are doing currently. If you must iterate through a loop and set all or few elements of the array in state, you can loop through the array and `push` all relevant items in a local array variable and set it to state after loop ends. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's because usually `react states` updates asynchronously and at the time you're checking for `slug` it hasn't set yet

you need to do something like this:

```
function Home(props) {
  const [performedFetch, setPerformedFetch] = useState(false);
  const [slug, setSlug] = useState(null);
  const [cardLocation, setCardLocation] = useState(1);
  const [card, setCard] = useState(null);
  const [publishDate, setPublishDate] = useState(null);

  const key = ""; // imagine these are here
  const token = "";

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlug(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("slug"));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(slug)
    if (!performedFetch && !!slug) {
      fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${listId}/cards?key=${key}&token=${token}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setPerformedFetch(true);

            data.forEach((c, index) => {
              if (c.desc.includes(slug)) {                    
                setCard(c)
                setCardLocation(index + 1)
              } else if (!publishDate && index > cardLocation) { 
                console.log(publishDate); // why is this always null?? also runs multiple times

                const name = c.name;
                const frontHalf = name.split("/")[0].split(" ");
                const month = frontHalf[frontHalf.length - 1];
                const day = name.split("/")[1].split(")")[0];
                setPublishDate(`${month}/${day}`);
              }
            });
        });
    }
  }, [slug, performedFetch])
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't correct. My code runs fine and the slug is pulled from the URL bar so the slug has nothing to do with anything async. I get into the else block and it continues to run through the cards I fetched. I'd expect it to stop after the first time I call `setPublishedDate`. Logging immediately after I set it still returns `null`.

Comment: @ZackShapiro , It's because React will ```batch``` all of your ```setPublishDate``` calls and will update ```state``` after you're checking the publish date

Comment: So how can I fix? Thanks